# Writing makeStyle in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, linear-gradients, makestyles

I need to write the following CSS value as a string  in a makeStyles function in Material UI, how can it be done?

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
    url(../assets/pexels-pixabay-41949.jpg),
```

i tried it this way but obviosuly is incorrect

```
background: 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
    url(../assets/pexels-pixabay-41949.jpg)',
```

Comment: If the newline in the string is in your actual source and not just formatted for here, that could be your problem. Strings are only 1 line long, if you want to break lines use `\n` in the string or use template syntax with `\`` instead of `'`. In this case you can choose either or just use 1 line without breaks, it is still valid CSS. but the code you posted is not valid JS

Comment: its actually one line not two ,  just not enough space for the whole string

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template literals to get this work. Move the URL into a variable and then form the actual CSS property.

```
const url = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588345921523-c2dcdb7f1dcd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80";
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    boxBackground: {
    background: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),url(${url
})`,
    },
  }));
```

Here is the working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixedcontainer-material-demo-forked-nbvf1s?file=/demo.tsx) link.